# SunOS tar filename is greater than 100

Tags: unix, tar

On a Solaris when creating a tar archive using the cf options:

```
tar cf file.tar dir
```

and when many nested directories generates very long path names, I get the error:

> tar: *filename*: filename is greater
>   than 100

**How to avoid it?**

Here is the details of the machine:

```
# uname -a
SunOS <box-name> 5.10 Generic_125100-10 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used the option `E`

> Write a tarfile with extended headers

So the command `tar cEf file.tar dir` worked smoothly

Comment: Using the -E option worked for me on Solaris, but it may not work properly if you want to extract the archive on another platform, which may not understand the header format as a result of the -E option.  For example, I was extracting the archive on Unbutu, and it could not properly decode certain filenames, such as ones containing the character é when the -E option was used on Solaris.  These filenames extracted fine on Ubuntu when I didn't use the -E option on Solaris.  I ended up using gtar on Solaris.

Comment: gtar is great, if you can have it! When I posted this question I was working on Solaris boxes with no permission to install or compile gtar...

Answer (score 4):

That's a restriction of pre-POSIX `tar`.  You can use `cpio -H ustar`, POSIX standard `pax`, or install GNU `tar`.

Comment: +1 for GNU tar. It also has extensions for handling compression.

Comment: Thank @geekosaur for the solutions proposed: (unfortunately) I can't install GNU tar but the cpio should work very well! Thanks

Comment: +1 GNU tar was available to me on Solaris SmartOS as `gtar`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a need for any of the other answers presented here.

Just use GNU tar. And yes, it is there!

You indicate your platform is Solaris 10. On this platform **GNU tar** is indeed installed by default. It lives in `/usr/sfw/bin` which may not be in your path, but it's there. Only if your sysadmin has installed Solaris with some minimal profile ('Core' or 'Reduced Network'), which is rare for sysadmins to do, will it not be there and you'll have to install package `SUNWgtar` from the installation media. I doubt that is the case. Just do `/usr/sfw/bin/gtar` and watch the magic.